# Nesting of ngx data table

Tags: swingx, ngx-datatable

Hi I am developing application in Angular5. I am using ngx data table. I have implemented row detail feature in my data grid. When i click on arrow mark, details will show down. Below is my code.

```
     <ngx-datatable #myTable class='material expandable'
                       [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
                       [rows]="rows"
                       [rowHeight]="35"
                       [headerHeight]="35"
                       [footerHeight]="35"
                       [columns]="columns"
                       [columnMode]="'force'"
                       [limit]="10">
      <ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="100" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
                <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
                    <div style="padding-left:35px;">
                    // Here I want to show columns with header and row of data
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-row-detail>

    <ngx-datatable-column [width]="50"
                              [resizeable]="false"
                              [sortable]="false"
                              [draggable]="false"
                              [canAutoResize]="false">
            <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                   [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded"
                   [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded"
                   title="Expand/Collapse Row"
                   (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
                </a>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column width="200">
            <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                Application ID
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{row.applicationid}}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
 </ngx-datatable>
```

In the above code, Whenever I click on row, below I want to display data with header and rows. I can display using plain html table. May I know is there any other way to display data as I mentioned or May I know how can I do this using ngx-data table? Can someone help me to figure it out this? Thank you.